# When is a better timing to inform the interviewers that I just left my current job during a recruiting process?

Tags: interviewing

I'm currently in a recruiting process. My headhunter set my first interview while I was still on my last job. Recently I got terminated by that firm on bad terms. During the first interview, they never asked me if I was still with that firm and I didn't say anything. But at the end of the conversation HR did ask if I plan to get my bonus first with the current firm.

For consistency and also not wanting creating new problems, I just said:

> I wouldn't miss a good opportunity for 1-2 months salary.

And I will go in for my second round of interviews.

I feel weird not telling them I already left the firm. So should I bring this up voluntarily? My mentor told me wait until they ask first. Also someone recommended me to tell them in the later stage.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you were [laid off or fired](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93905)? Either way it's likely a duplicate of [Should I tell the company I'm interviewing with I've been laid off](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/should-i-tell-the-company-im-interviewing-with-im-laid-off)

Answer (score 5):

> So should I bring this up voluntarily? My mentor told me wait until
>   they ask first.

Your mentor is right. Don't bring up the issue unless asked.

But be careful here. If you come across as misleading or a liar, you may very well be dropped from consideration.

Answering "I wouldn't miss a good opportunity for 1-2 months salary." in response to a question about staying at a company to get a bonus from your current firm isn't *technically* lying. But if that interviewer finds out that you couldn't stay for the bonus even if you wanted to, they may feel mislead.

A typical interview question is "Why do you want to leave your current job?" If asked something like that, you should consider indicating that you are no longer working there. That could easily lead into a discussion as to why.

Be prepared to answer why you were terminated, what were the bad terms, what you have since learned, and how you won't let that happen again in the future. Practice your answer. Make sure it comes across well. Enlist a friend to role play if necessary.